# Java: Unboxing values stored in an Object to an unknown type

Tags: java, generics, boxing, autoboxing, unboxing

I am building something like a data flow graph, with nodes and connections that pass data between them. The base class in this case is `ValueTarget<T>`, which has a previous and a next target to pass data back and forth. Other classes extend this class to provide sources for the data, merge data (e.g. a multiplication) etc.

Now, I wanted to write a data source that takes its value from any given method. It takes a `java.lang.reflect.Method` instance (and the Object and parameters to invoke it) and uses this to set the data:

```
@Override
public T getValue() {

    if (valueCalculator != null) {
        try {
            Object result = valueCalculator.invoke(sourceObject);
            T typedResult = (T)(result);
            return typedResult;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return super.getValue();
}
```

Now, I have tried this with the `public int getLength()` Method of another object. However, in the graph, I need to map this method to a `float` result. The given typecast doesn't throw an Exception, but when reading the last `ValueTarget<Float>`'s value and using its result as a `float` parameter to another method, the program crashes, stating that "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float".

Now, I am aware that Integer and Float are boxed and therefore cannot be cast into each other's type. However, **as the types are all handled using the generics, I cannot unbox to a specific type.**

Is there any way to perform a generic unboxing in order to be able to cast boxed values into the according value-types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `Number.floatValue()`?

```
Object result = valueCalculator.invoke(sourceObject);
Float f = ((Number)result).floatValue();
System.out.println(f);
```

... or however you want to use it.

Here I'm assuming the return type is one of these - `BigDecimal`, `BigInteger`, `Byte`, `Double`, `Float`, `Integer`, `Long`, and `Short` (which are all subclasses of `Number`).

Comment: If result can't be typecast to Number then again it will throw type cast error.

Comment: @Vijay If it can't be typecast to `Number`, I'm not sure what the behaviour should be then. There is no generic method that allows for other conversions, thus no generic solution.

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not this is how you meant it, but by simply using <Number> as the smallest common denominator to pass numbers through the graph instead of using particular types such as Float, I could bypass the whole problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache CommonBeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) library to convert types at runtime.

```
org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils.convert(Object value, Class targetType)
```

so you change the typecaste code

```
  T typedResult = (T)(result);
```

replace with this

```
 T typedResult = (T)org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils.convert(result, T.getClass());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the error still remains: The program still crashes with "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float" when using the (supposed) Float result somewhere else.

Comment: Try the instanceof keyword.